# Default activity not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

A read most of the same questions but no one of them could help me, so i am asking by myself. 
Here is my android manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.abcdev.starksproject" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RestaurantDetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FeedDetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderDetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".OrderActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CartActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".OrderActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CommentActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <service
        android:name=".Sevice.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
</application>
```

I defined LAUNCHER activity and package name is correct. Studio can see activities and when i run app by choosing activity by myself it works great, so i have no ideas what can it be. I hope some one knows whats wrong.

Comment: you don't have to assign default category to each Activity. lest system decide by it self.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing??? if there is any error add the logcat

Comment: `ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION` and `ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY` should not be capitalized anywhere.

Comment: @MikeM. *should not* is too weak. *must not* is more appropriate

Comment: In addition, you have defined **8** Activities as your DEFAULT Activity.

Comment: Instead of using a bunch of Activities, you *could* (I'm tempted to say that you *should*) use only **1**. And replace the current Fragment inside that Activity.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks a lot, it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Same goes for

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Same goes for `.MainActivity`, though.

Comment: No need to specify other Activity as
 <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>